# Creating Interactive graphs like Stack exchange reputation tab

Tags: pdftex, animations, intersections

I like to prepare an interactive timeline graph (static on load, but dynamic on `MouseHover` event). Somehow is similar to the Stack-exchange reputation tab for an user. One classic example is [**here**](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation). When the page loads, it shows the graph with separate colored lines for every sites. But, on `mouse hover` at any point an `interactive pop-up` shows the status of reputation on that particular day of that user.

Since this is a regular task for me to prepare a Record Tracker every day. I wish to automate this by:

- preparing a template for the report (containing only the graph),
- connecting to an external `CSV` containing data, on which basis the report would be generated,
- and finally add some interactivity like the [**previous link**](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation).

Connecting to database is some how I have managed using `datatool` package. But, I have no idea how to create a PDF file, that is ***`static on load`*** but ***`dynamic on hover`***.

I have gone through some animated examples from `animate` package. But, not able to find any specific package to use in this occasion. Being less-known in this field, I wish if someone guides me to the way to get the solution.

I am unsure whether this could be done in `LaTeX` or not. Is this possible using `LaTeX` at all? Any help (either some code or pointing out some resources) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: pdf allows a certain amount of interactivity but isn't that kind of "dynamic on hover" behaviour more suited to html/javascript, as in the example graphs that you gave?

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, for your prompt response, to make me sure, that what I am trying to achive is impossible, as PDF does not supports something like `hover` events.  I rather have to choose any other way. Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible to do in pdf but pdf is at its heart a format for typeset text in a fixed layout, modern versions have more interactivity and javascript etc, but they are not supported in all pdf viewers and the more fluid html format just seems a better fit for that kind of thing

Comment: Sir, I am going to be too rigid on this. As I am looking forward to get the job done by`ocgx`. But, still I wonder if there is really a way to do the same thing with hover effect , no matter if only a few PDF browers supports that. And I would highly obliged if you point me to some of these resources. Thank you, Sir.

Comment: My comment was just a general observation rather than something backed up with technical links. Glad to see you got up to date information in the other answer. (By the way, no need to be too formal around here, you can drop the "sir":-)

Comment: @Cylian In theory it should be possible with mouseover like in `cooltooltips.sty`. But this certainly requires Javascript. I don't know how well OCGs are supported in Adobe Javascript API. This API is just supported by Adobe AFAIK. Contact the maintainer of `ocgx.sty` for a feature request. Maybe he can implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a job for OCGs, if you do not insist on mouseover but can live with clicks. See [parindent in TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74877/parindent-in-tikz-node) for my question on `ocgx.sty`. It can toggle the visibility of OCG layers.

Take also a look at the [demo](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf) file of the package.

Comment: Well that's really cool! But, i think I have to update pacakes for this... As I am using MiKTeX 2.8. Anyway it seems to match my requirement. Thanks again for your help!