# How to enlarge a picture on click?

Tags: floats, interaction

I am trying to create a technical manual which contains a lot of screen-shots. Nevertheless I am looking for:

- Insert the pictures as thumbnails and when one clicks on them, they expand as embedded pictures.

Can that behaviour be achieved using the LaTeX technology?

If the answer is yes, can you suggest some tips about it, please?

Comment: This sounds very problematic - once the image is scaled up then the whole document has to be re-built, as you can no longer assure that the larger version is in the right place.

Comment: What about the captions? Should they initially be also reduced in the thumbnails and enlarged after clicking on the thumbnail?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not necessarily, but that's a plus :)

Comment: You can link the thumbnail to a full image (in a separate file) using hyperref.

Answer (score 10):

This question has already been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12293) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4323). They define a `\zoombox` macro to be used, e. g., as:

```
\zoombox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{screenshot-1}}
\zoombox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{screenshot-2}}
\zoombox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{screenshot-3}}
...
```

On click, the box content is zoomed to its maximum size possible to fit within the Adobe Reader document window.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible with an interactive format like PDF. Sounds like a job for OCGs. See:

1. [parindent in TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74877/parindent-in-tikz-node)
2. [Creating Interactive graphs like Stack exchange reputation tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/creating-interactive-graphs-like-stack-exchange-reputation-tab/103937#103937)

`ocgx.sty` can toggle the visibility of OCG layers. Support by other viewers but AR might be, well ... ;-)

Comment: Walking around @Josep suggestions, I've found an `Undefined Control Sequence` at line 119 of `ocg-p` package. Does anyone know how to fix that?